# Why kerberos using hashes

Tags: hash, kerberos

Can you explain me the exact reasons and benefits of using hashes of password instead of the passwords themselves? 
Because parcticly if you got hash of user you can authenticate as that user, and anyway the password is invisible.

Comment: This question should be asked on [security.se] rather than StackOverflow, as it is a question about protocol design rather than a question about writing code.

Comment: That said, in general, user-selected passwords make very weak keys -- it's easy to predict lots of bits in them. A one-way cryptographic hash of a user-selected password is more resistant to cryptanalysis (when used as an encryption key) than the password itself, because the hash function results in evenly distributed (random-looking) bits that don't have much relation to each other.

Comment: ...if I might suggest [Security Engineering, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780470068526.do), it covers the protocol's design considerations in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more secure to store a hash of a password rather than a password itself (e.g. in keytab).

Kerberos only transfers over network encrypted Authenticator with its own copy of a secret key. Authenticator contains unique information about the client (for example, client name, client realm, the time on the client, and so forth). Each Authenticator is unique, because of the time information it contains.

So information transferred over network can't be reused (replayed later by an attacker), as Authenticator is unique and depends on time.

Hope this helps. With Kerberos you don't have password stored nor transferred over network. Which makes it more secure.